# Bluetooth connection issues in Ubuntu 14.04 installed in ASUS F451-CA

Tags: bluetooth

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 in my recently bought Laptop ASUS  F451-CA and i have problems with the Bluetooth connection. I have installed Blueman Bluetooth Manager which shows that the bluetooth is switched on but other connection options dont work and i am unable to connect with devices using Bluetooth.

Comment: Can you add the results from terminal of the following commands `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net` and `lsusb`

Comment: Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
No command 'lpsci' found, did you mean:
 Command 'lspci' from package 'pciutils' (main)
lpsci: command not found

Comment: lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b404 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 152d:2509 JMicron Technology Corp. / JMicron USA Technology Corp. JMS539 SuperSpeed SATA II 3.0G Bridge
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Comment: I am not seeing any indication that this laptop is even equipped with bluetooth, so I cannot help

Answer (score 0):

Try installing bluez-utils it may help... and do:

```
hcitool inq
hcitool scan
```

from command line. See if it gives you information about bluetooth devices near you.

Comment: ~$ hcitool inq
Inquiring ...
Inquiry failed.: No such device

Comment: ~$ hcitool scan
Device is not available: No such device

Comment: try: hciconfig -a ..??  Does it shows you any device??